# Как сделать footer в низу страницы

Tags: css

Не могу что фетур был в низу страницы при появлении заглушки...
Пример тут [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oxhrh3wd/1/)

html:

```
<body>
  <div class="cap">
 cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>cap<br>
  </div>
  <div class="page">page</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.cap {
  position: absolute;
}
.page {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Если прокрутить вниз страницы, то .cap вылазит за приделы футера (а нужно что бы футер тоже был в низу страницы), .cap должен быть поверх страницы...

Comment: У тебя ведь `.cap` позиция назначена `position: absolute` и он просто выйдет в следующий так называемый слой, и будет поверх других блоков...) И это же препятствует твоему футеру. Попробуй фиксированную позицию что-ли...

Comment: @KryTer_NexT контент который будет подгружаться в .cap может быть больше чем размер страницы, можно сделать со .cap я знаю, но то есть вариантов сss нет?

Comment: Можно сделать так называемый 'резиновый' футер, просто при добавлении контента, футер вниз уходил вместе с контентом, а в css: `postion: absolute` убрать и сделать отдельный блочный элемент, этот `position: absolute` ужасная вещь, с нею трудно работать особенно если ты верстаешь сайт не только для экрана с одним разрешением..

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в адаптивном сайте с изменяемой высотой футера, прибить его к низу страницы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579340/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прижимать footer всегда к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.header,.footer{
  width:90%;
  margin:3px auto;
  background:rgba(200,200,200,.4);
}
.header{
 height:120px;
}
.footer{
  height:140px;
}
.clear{
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
.clear:after{
 content:"";
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
.main{
 width:90%;
 margin:3px auto;
}
.aside,.article{
 float:left;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 background:rgba(200,200,200,.4);
}
.aside{
 width:30%;
 min-height:150px;
}
.article{
 width:69%;
 min-height:200px;
 margin-left:1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> header </div>
<div class="main clear"> 
   <div class="aside">aside</div>
   <div class="article">article</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Ну собственно сама разметка , как видно не сложная , подвал сам оказывается в само низу , вот и всё 
Позиционированием в этом случае не надо пользоваться