# Как в адаптивном сайте с изменяемой высотой футера, прибить его к низу страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Есть адаптивный сайт на bootstrap. На некоторых страницах футер "подпрыгивает" вверх. Нужно чтобы он всегда был прижат к низу. У футера высота не фиксированная,гугл не помогает.

http://dn.hqsale.com/edit.php# - можно увидеть здесь, при просмотре 768 на 1024

Заранее спасибо

Comment: А вы можете уточнить к низу страницы или к низу экрана? и можете также выбрать ответ как принятый или написать уточняющие комментарии, если такового нет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прижимать footer всегда к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Comment: @Vadizar, здесь идёт речь о конкретно bootstap-овском решении.

Answer (score 1):

```
<footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom"> .... </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас на сайте добавляются и удаляются элементы при просмотре на разных устройствах, естественно он будет меняться советую поиграться с CSS а именно с min-height, max-height, min-width, max-width.